# Unable to fit BERT model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I am trying to train a BERT model based on an online tutorial (Coursera). The objective is to use the Quora insincere questions data to train a BERT model. The entire code is shown below:

```
# Function to fine-tune BERT for Text Classification
# bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2', trainable=True) 
def fine_tune(bert_layer, tokenizer, train_data, valid_data):
    model = create_model(bert_layer)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=2e-5),
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
    print(model.summary())

    # Train the model
    epochs = 4
    history = model.fit(train_data,
                        validation_data=valid_data,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        verbose=1)
```

However, I get the following error when running the model at model.fit():

```
Epoch 1/4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-21a1de6e4ed2> in <module>()
    166     train_model()
    167 
--> 168 main()

3 frames
<ipython-input-5-21a1de6e4ed2> in main()
    164 def main():
    165     # check_version()
--> 166     train_model()
    167 
    168 main()

<ipython-input-5-21a1de6e4ed2> in train_model()
     70 
     71         # Run the model
---> 72         fine_tune(bert_layer, tokenizer, train_data, valid_data)
     73 
     74 def prepare_bert():

<ipython-input-5-21a1de6e4ed2> in fine_tune(bert_layer, tokenizer, train_data, valid_data)
    148                         validation_data=valid_data,
    149                         epochs=epochs,
--> 150                         verbose=1)
    151 
    152     plot_graphs(history, 'binary_accuracy')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1108 
   1109         if logs is None:
-> 1110           raise ValueError('Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.')
   1111         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
   1112 

ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.
```

The train data is prepared as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.org/download/fine-tune-bert-tensorflow-train.csv/train.csv.zip', compression='zip', low_memory=True) 

train_df, remaining = train_test_split(df, random_state=42, train_size=0.0075, stratify=df.target.values) 

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((train_df['question_text'].values, train_df['target'].values)) 

train_data = (train_data.map(to_feature_map,
                                     num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                      # .cache()
                      .shuffle(1000)
                      .batch(32, drop_remainder=True)
                      .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))
```

I get the following when I print train_data.element_spec:

```
({'input_word_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(32, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'input_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(32, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'input_type_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(32, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}, TensorSpec(shape=(32,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
```

This would mean the train_data is non-empty.

How can I resolve this problem? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I would appreciate any help in resolving the bug.

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with the train_data variable - can you check the shape and make sure it's not empty before it get's passed to the fine_tune function?

Comment: hi @ML_Engine, I have updated my query with code used to process the training data. It shows that train_data is non-empty.

Comment: My guess is that you should change `from_tensors` to `from_tensor_slices`. You need to post the code for building `train_df` to say for sure.

Comment: Many thanks @BjörnLindqvist, that did the trick.

Comment: Also your train_size parameter is tiny, less than 1% of your data is being allocated to the train set if I'm not mistaken. Maybe you wanted 0.75?

Comment: Thanks @ML_Engine, the fractions were from tutorial recommendations. The model seems to work fine now.